# import contacts from sim to phone only

Tags: contacts, sim-card, import

I have to set up an android phone (Orange Boston, Android 2.1-update1) for a colleague.
I added two accounts, one gmail and one exchange, both only used for mail & calendar.

Now my colleague has several contacts on the sim card that he wants to import onto the phone, and the phone only.
But when I click "Import from SIM" in the contacts app I have to choose an account (gmail or roadsync (exchange app)).
I do not want them to sync to anything, just be on the phone.

I found several guides that showed that there should be a "phone only, unsynched" option, but I don't have that.

What can I do to import the contacts phone only?

Answer (score 1):

In the contacts menu do you have a menu item called accounts? It should show which accounts are synched up and also have the option to not sync to any account. You could turn sync to accounts off here and may then be able to import contacts to phone only.

Alternatively you could make sure the phone is not connected to the internet (wifi or data), import the contacts into one of the accounts, then go into settings and switch sync contacts off for both the accounts available.